# allow ssh connection from remote host

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

I've just started playing around with SSH tunnels today, but I'm stick at a bit of a silly point (I think)... Probably just missing something obvious but here goes:

I've got two linux servers and a single windows client (server1, server2, client). I've set up server1 to create a reverse ssh tunnel to server2, like so:

```
ssh -nNfR 8022:localhost:22 user@server1
```

After which I can successfully get a shell on on server1 using:

```
ssh -p 8022 localhost
```

Logically, this leads me to think that I should be able to create a putty ssh connection to server1:8022 and get a shell for server2, but I get a connection refused error. Anyone know what I'm missing or am I entirely on the wrong track :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem.  You need to enable port access on the server.  Modify **GatewayPorts** to **yes** in **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**.

see **man sshd_config** under **GatewayPorts**.

You may also need to specify a bind address to your tunnel setup:

```
ssh -nNfR *:8022:localhost:22 user@server1
```

to bind to all interfaces.

see **man ssh** under **-R**

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
 ssh -nNfR 8022:localhost:22 user@server1
```

That is basically saying 'open the 8022 port on server1 connecting to localhost port 22', but 'localhost' on server1 its... server1 :) try with:

```
 ssh -nNfR 8022:server2:22 user@server1
```

Also, when you use 'localhost' on the first command you bind your port to the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) that doesn't accept connections from outside, try it with the server1 hostname or IP to check :)

Comment: After playing around with it a bit, I believe your first suggestion is incorrect, although your second suggestion was part of the solution.